# Error when having 2 properties/relationships of same type with EF4 Code First

Tags: many-to-many, entity-relationship, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have a class X that has a many to many relationship with Y. If I only have that property then EF will correctly produce the 3rd XY table. However if I want to have that many to many relationship to type X AND also have a 1 to many relationship to Y.

To illustrate say I have something like this:

```
class Location
{
  public ICollection<Person> Visitors {get;set;}
}

class Person
{
  public Location Home {get;set}
  public ICollection<Location> VisitedPlaces {get;set;}
}
```

When I have both references, EF stops genereting the 3rd table and only gives me a 1 to 1 relationship for each property!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add this to your derived context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasRequired(p => p.Home)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

The problem is that EF is not able to infer correctly the mapping because it doesn't  know if `Visitors` collection in `Location` class is part of declared many-to-many relation or one-to-many relation (it can't be part of both). My example defines that one-to-many relation doesn't have navigation property on `Location` so EF now knows that it is part of many-to-many relation.